# Pyinstaller Hidden imports and user defined modules error

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, command-prompt

[image]

Basically I made a GUI app and it has a lot of user defined modules stored in different py files. All of these py files have been imported as modules in the main file but whenever i run the executable this exception is generated in the command prompt. I have no idea how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtualenv you should use the `"-p" or "--path='D:...'"` option. Like this:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --paths=D:\env\Lib\site-packages  .\foo.py
```

What this does is generates foo.spec file with this pathex path

Comment: Actually i am just using this command in the command prompt pyinstaller -i "Cheficon.ico" -w Biteoclock.py

Comment: I am not using virtualenv